# Importing/Exporting Views in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-view

I was trying to move a database from one machine to another, and decided to enlist the Import/Export functionality to help in my cause.  Everything went great, except that all of my views had been turned into tables.

After some digging, I found this: "[If the source data is a view, the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard automatically converts the view to a table in the destination.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052(v=sql.105).aspx)"

Does anyone know how this automatic "feature" could be disabled? or a pain free way to re build my views after only importing the tables?  I've tried some "CREATE to" scripts, but they keep failing, and I can't think of another way to preserve the structure of my database.

Comment: it would be easiest to take a database backup and restore it to your destination, that way everything would be intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Import/Export wizard is not what you are after.

> I can't think of another way to preserve the structure of my database.

There is a 'Copy Database' wizard, but personally I prefer to take a backup of the database, then restore the backup to the new instance.

**Edit:**
Starting point for references on both options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189624(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'll look into that.  Do you have a good resource on hand that explains the process? I'm new to this.

Comment: The Copy Database wizard seems fairly intuitive.  For resources, you could start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Everything is just as it was on the old machine.  I ended up using the backup and restore method, which worked perfect.